# follow cursor using transforms and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, transform

One of the first widgets for laptops was the face of a cat whose eyes followed the movement of the mouse cursor.  (For you newbies, this was necessary because the screens were black and white and totally crappy.)

Several years ago I did a blow-up of this as a background image using Java - totally awesome.

Would like to resurrect the idea, and seems (in theory) should be pretty straightforward using using css3 transforms and javascript sitting on the mouse move event.  Anybody know of anybody pulling this off?

Comment: Found a bunch of scripts in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=follow+eyes+javascript&oq=follow+eyes+javascript&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l2j69i62l3.3013j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @elclanrs - thanks for the link.  looking at http://userbag.co.uk/development/javascript-eyes-that-follow-the-cursor/